# Upgrading to Rails 6.1.6.1 causes Psych::DisallowedClass: Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When upgrading to Rails 6.1.6.1, I started getting the following error in the application:

```
Psych::DisallowedClass:
        Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol
```

This is being caused by using the `Hash` serializer on an ActiveRecord column, which uses Symbols as keys or values:

```
serialize :parameters, Hash
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The error occurs due to the following security update in Rails:
https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cve-2022-32224-possible-rce-escalation-bug-with-serialized-columns-in-active-record/81017

The `Hash` serializer apparently loaded data with `YAML.unsafe_load`, which now changed to `YAML.safe_load`. This new method does not handle data types such as `Symbol` or `Time` by default for security reasons.

The workaround as the [announcement](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cve-2022-32224-possible-rce-escalation-bug-with-serialized-columns-in-active-record/81017) suggests is to either migrate the serializer to JSON or use only safe data types in the serialization (Strings, Numbers).

However, there are two configurable quick workarounds though:

```
config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load
```

This is not recommended as it basically reverts back to the old behaviour.

OR

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol]
```

Which allows serializing Symbols or other unsupported (or unsafe) data types.

Comment: I'm wondering why `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is not included by default in the list of permitted classes. Not sure if might be unsafe

Comment: I had to do `config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load = true` for it to work

Comment: so if I use this one:

`config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol]`

and add a bunch of other classes like `Date` `Time` `HashWithIndifferentAccess` `MyCustomClass`

Is that still a big security hole or not?

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 I don't know exactly which types might be prone to RCE issues due to SQL injection but as long as that field does not contain user generated content, you should be fine. Otherwise, I'd definitely move to JSON

Comment: thanks @mrstif . It does contain user generated content. But it gets sanitized by `Rails::Html::SafeListSanitizer` before being saved to the db. I wonder if that is good enough or not..

Comment: what if I am using ActiveRecord without a rails app ?

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 Yeah, the idea is that the upgrade is to increase security within the application.  If you're doing things that cancel this, then you're subject to the same security risks that the Rails maintainers were concerned about.

Comment: @mrstif Are you saying that Symbol is susceptible to arbitrary code execution? I believe that Symbol is as secure as others. If you look in the active_record.rb file of the activerecord library, you will see the usage of the line indicated in the CVE used in the main branch: github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/… Patterson does not point out any classes as insecure and nor Psych, he only accepts those widely considered "safe", I believe they are adopting a conservative stance. I believes that security is not allied to one class. Would like to know what you think about it, thanks!

Comment: hey @amystherdam It's true that Symbol is as secure or dangerous as others. This just enforces to make the decision on which of those you consider safe in your own application. 
Anyway, as I mentioned, I'd really advise migrating to json instead.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to migrate a field with YAML strings to one with JSON?  I can't just change the type of serialization, for I assume it would break when reading from records that pre-dated the change.  Anyone have an example of a migration that converts existing serialized attributes?

Answer (score 7):

In case anybody else gets stuck on this, none of the two fixes suggested above and in the Rails security update worked for me on Rails `5.2.8.1`, I kept having the same error (`Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol`) despite allowing it with `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol]` in `application.rb`.
In the end I had to adjust the unsafe_load option as per @ryan2johnson9's first comment for it to work:

```rb
config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load = true
```

Answer (score 5):

Found this handy as well.

```
    config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date]
```