# Why is changeset for Paper Trail empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem, psych

I recently upgraded my Ruby to 3.1.2 and Rails to 7.0.3.1.

Somewhere in the changes, one problem I noticed is that my Paper Trails (paper_trails gem) info was now not working, at least with respect to the details.

None of the "changeset" data was available, as so my tests were failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to application.rb:

```rb
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone]
```

Make sure you restart your server.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. While I didn't say that in my answer, what you suggest is what I did. (Well, I actually added: [BigDecimal, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess,ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone, Time]). Your answer makes explicit the next step, my answer would require the reader to go to those links.  I've accepted your answer. BTW, I have no idea why this is needed (maybe I knew when I added them). I guess it has to do with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72970170/upgrading-to-rails-6-1-6-1-causes-psychdisallowedclass-tried-to-load-unspecif?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I put a "byebug" in the view that used the data and looked for what was missing.  Apparently my "changeset" data was all missing.

Using this link:

[Upgrading to Rails 6.1.6.1 causes Psych::DisallowedClass: Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72970170/upgrading-to-rails-6-1-6-1-causes-psychdisallowedclass-tried-to-load-unspecif)

And these:

https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/446

https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/490

I guessed it was a disallowed class problem, and I ultimately sat on that view breakpoint running

`PaperTrail.serializer.load(change_history_by_month.object_changes)` (your parameter will be different of course)

until it output the right data. The basic problem apparently was Pysch, and several disallowed classes (for example, "Psych::DisallowedClass Exception: Tried to load unspecified class: BigDecimal"), but fortunately the above will tell you the classes and you can add them to config/application.rb

Very frustrating as it was all quiet, without warnings or errors.

Of course, the classes aren't disallowed for nothing.  There may be a security problem here with allowing these classes.

Comment: I am surprised that there were not exceptions recorded in the log file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @spickermann. Could be in there somewhere, but I'm not seeing it.  Not CodeNoob for nothing though ;).